# Error in if (tolower(e) %in% c(".tiff", ".tif")) { : the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, r-raster

Anyone able to help me with that?

```
raster::writeRaster(x = var_br_05, 
                    filename = paste0("wc14_br_res05g_", names(var_br)), 
                     bylayer = TRUE, 
                     options = c("COMPRESS=DEFLATE"), 
                     format = "GTiff", 
                     overwrite = TRUE)
```

```
Error in if (tolower(e) %in% c(".tiff", ".tif")) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

Comment: Try `names(var_br)[1]`- you are passing a vector of file names instead of a single file name

Comment: Are you on R version 4.2?

Comment: Yes, it's ver 4.2.